# Computer will not boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, hardware

this is my first time using/installing ubuntu. I booted from a usb and it was running, however when i started to "install" it for the second time (getting rid of windows completely) half way through this second install the laptop froze. I shut it down and to my horror it will not start, it just has a black screen with a cursor bar flashing in the top right hand corner.

I assume that it didn't fully install ubuntu and it wiped windows and it wont load ubuntu as i need windows to do that.

any ideas on how to fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the laptop froze? I mean, how you got that the laptop froze?

Comment: Did you do any partitions? What's your disk-filesystem; is it NTFS or ext4..?

Comment: Is it a Samsung? There are a few models that have broken firmware and can be bricked permanently by installing Linux. A workaround was put in the Kernel meanwhile to disable the problematic driver on broken laptops, but I have no idea if it is included in Ubuntu already. http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Booting-Linux-using-UEFI-can-brick-Samsung-laptops-1793958.html

Comment: It is an Asus aspire one, i know it froze as it was unresponsive for 10 minutes

Comment: If you are unable to boot any OS from USB you either A) Have neglected to change the boot order in BIOS to choose your installation media or B) Have a serious hardware problem. I concur with Vinoth.3v "Please have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick "

Answer (score 1):

You have to boot again from flash/dvd and fix or reinstall ubuntu again using ubuntu installation wizard. 
Please use the bootable USB, or use the Ubuntu Live CD/DVD, so you can boot from usb or dvd. it will help to recover the system,

Comment: I cannot boot the computer at all, windows does not open on it. all that opens is a "setup menu" by pressing the f2 key

Comment: Please use the bootable USB, or use the Ubuntu Live CD/DVD, so you can boot from usb or dvd. it will help to recover the system,

Comment: I know your trying to help but it doesnt recognise that there is a usb drive in, it only goes o a black screen and i cannot move any further than that

Comment: Please have a look at [install from USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Comment: THey computer does not start up... I have said that 3 times now... Even without the usb the computer will not start. I have read all of those and none of them contain the answer. Hence the reason i have come here for help. DO not continue commenting if you are going to continue to say the same thing, when i tell you form the start that it does not work...